# Which winapi function does the Process Explorer use to suspend process?

Tags: c++, winapi, systems-programming

I am attempting to write a hook which will catch "**SomeFunction**" of **Process Explorer** that suspends process. I already have a solution which hooks functions such as **SuspendThread** and **NtSuspendThread**. But the Process Explorer use something different and I don't know what. Please can anyone tell me the **name of the function** used by PE to suspend process?

Comment: Have you checked the import table?  Have you done anything at all to help yourself before asking here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attach it to an API Monitor; It calls `NtOpenProcess -> NtSuspendProcess()`

[image: SShot]

Comment: What API monitor did you use here?

Comment: Thanks, that looks very nice. I'll dig into it some more, always in the market for good tools.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I tried to hook NtSuspendThread in procexp.exe but without results. I hooked this function in procexp64.exe and it works!!! Thanks a lot!!!